# How can I position a div fixed relative to the body, when it's inside a fixed parent div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

I'm currently working on a CSS layout where I have a **fixed parent div** containing another div. I want the inner div to be **fixed relative to the body**, not its parent.

Code (Tailwind):

```
<div class="h-screen bg-red-100">
  <div class="fixed left-1/2 top-1/2 h-80 w-80 -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 bg-red-300">
    <div class="fixed top-10 h-40 w-40 bg-red-600">I want to make this div fixed relative to body</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Tailwind Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/mebT9Uz05X)

Is there a way to achieve this without JavaScript? If not, how can I accomplish it using JavaScript?

I've also researched extensively and searched on Stack Overflow, but I couldn't find a solution that fits my exact requirements.

Thank you!

**More Info:**

Based on **@Paulie_D** and **@Yogi** 's replies, I checked once again in my code. If I am using any translate property in my code, then I found out that it's for modal opening and closing `transition` (opening from top to down and closing from down to top). I have added the translate property for this purpose.

```
 <div
      role="dialog"
      aria-modal="true"
      tabIndex="-1"
      onKeyDown={handleTabKey}
      ref={modalRef}
      className={`fixed top-0 left-0 inset-0 flex justify-center items-center bg-black z-50 bg-opacity-50 backdrop-blur-sm ${
        isModalOpen ? "opacity-100" : "opacity-0 pointer-events-none"
      } transition-all ease-in-out`}
    >
      <div
        className={`bg-white rounded-md w-[30%] p-3 tb:p-6 ${
          isModalOpen ? "translate-y-0" : "-translate-y-full"
        } transition-all ease-in-out`}
      >
        . . . .
     </div>
    </div>
```

Now I am going to remove it, but please, can anyone help me with how we can achieve the same **transition without the translate property**?

Comment: What is stopping you to move it out of `"h-screen bg-red-100"` div?

Comment: Just to clarify, the `bg-red-100 h-screen` div structure provided is only an example, and in my actual project, the structure is more complex.

Moving this div outside of that div would require significant restructuring, which isn't feasible at the moment.

However, I appreciate your suggestion. If there's no straightforward CSS solution, I'd be open to exploring JavaScript alternatives, explaining the entire project scenario might be quite difficult for me.

Comment: Just to move the fixed  child div out of the  fixed  parent div if they have no relation on postion.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is presenting an issue for you. A `position: fixed` element is **always** positioned in relation to the `body` *but* you have to specify *where* it is positioned. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/KKYXaZB

Comment: does this work? https://play.tailwindcss.com/oxLUCRm7ch

Comment: If you're using position fixed and want something to slide down from the top, you can position based on a `bottom` value instead of `top`. Using `bottom: 100%` will shove the element fully offscreen above the visible area, then when you want to drop it down you reduce that value to wherever you want to position the element onscreen

Answer (score 2):

**Remove Transforms from Parent Element**

The [specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering) note:

> Any value other than none for the transform property also causes the
> element to establish a containing block for all descendants. Its
> padding box will be used to layout for all of its absolute-position
> descendants, fixed-position descendants, and descendant fixed
> background attachments.

OP's code breaks fixed positioning by using a translate transform to center the parent element on the page.

Fix the problem by using flex to center the parent element without a transform.  This can be done using Tailwind flex classes. This centers the parent without affecting the fixed positioning of the child element.

*Tailwind References:* [Flex](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex) , [Align Items](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/align-items) , [Align Content](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/align-content)

**Code Snippet**

```html
<div class="flex justify-center items-center h-screen bg-blue-100">
  <div class="fixed top-20 h-80 w-80  bg-red-300">
    parent - centered
    <div class="fixed top-10 left-0 h-40 w-40 bg-green-600 text-white">
    child - fixed to body
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `position: relative` in the second child or parent or body and `position: fixed` on the third:

Code:

```
<div class="flex justify-center items-center h-screen bg-red-100">
  <div class="h-80 w-80 bg-red-300">
    <div class="fixed left-0 top-0 flex h-40 w-40 items-center justify-center bg-red-600">I want to make this div fixed relative to body</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

External CSS:

```
body {
  position: relative;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: What's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding position:relative to the nested div?
[Fiddle with CSS example](https://jsfiddle.net/S2Kaw/2/)

```css
.container-div {
  padding: 10px 10px 0;
background-color:#c3c3c3;
width:200px;
}

.child-div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  position:relative;
    top:-20px;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<br><br><div class="container-div">
  <div class="child-div">
This div appears to be nested.
  </div>
</div>
```